# Does $f(x)=g(x) \implies S$ imply $h(f(x))= h(g(x)) \implies S$?

Tags: functions, logic

This is a question about mathematical logic and functions - defined in the usual way to map an input to only one output.

If we are given the following,

$$f(x)=g(x) \implies S$$

can we then say the following is also true?

$$h(f(x))= h(g(x)) \implies S$$

**Question:** If yes, why is this true?

---

Here, $S$ is some logical proposition. Also, $f$ and $g$ are functions with the same domain $X$, where $x \in X$, and whose codomain is the domain of the function $h$.

Comment: Not if h is a constant map.

Comment: This is not true. Compare $x = |x| \implies x \geq 0$, which holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, with $x^2 = |x|^2 \implies x \geq 0$, which is not.

Comment: The statement is true if $h$ is injective, but not in general. On the other hand, the converse is always true regardless of whether or not $h$ is injective.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang what is it about injectivity that makes this work?

Comment: @Penelope: The definition of injectivity of $h$ is literally that $h(x)=h(y)\implies x=y$ holds for all $x,y$. So if you knew $h(f(x))=h(g(x))$, you'd be able to conclude $f(x)=g(x)$ by the definition of injectivity, and from that you'd be able to conclude $S$ by the first implication.

Comment: Perhaps some quantifiers are missing?

Comment: Indeed, is this for specific $f$ and $g$ or for arbitrary $f$ and $g$? For all $x$? For a particular $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general the second implication is stronger than the first, so we can't necessarily say it's true. For an easy example, take any function $h$ that's not injective and some $x$ where which $h(f(x)) = h(g(x))$, but $f(x) \neq g(x)$. The proposition $S$ could literally be "the LHS equals the RHS".

More generally, when we have an implication $P \Rightarrow Q$, if we strengthen the hypothesis (find some $P'$ such that $P' \Rightarrow P$) or weaken the conclusion (find some $Q'$ such that $Q \Rightarrow Q'$) then
$$
(P \Rightarrow Q) \implies (P' \Rightarrow Q'), 
$$
but not necessarily the converse.

Comment: if $h$ is injective, then does the second implication hold? If yes, I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of injective. A function $h: A \to B$ is *injective* means that 
$$
h(a) = h(b) \implies a = b, 
$$
or stated in the contrapositive (which may be more *intuitive* if less useful): 
$$
a \neq b \implies h(a) \neq h(b).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be a false statement.

Construct an example where $f(x)=g(x)$ is false (so that the first implication is true), while $h(f(x))=h(g(x))$ is true (so that the second implication is false).